# Changing Specific Cell Condition to a Range Condition

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to run a macro automatically when a cell changed(its value is equal or greater than "1") on `G1:G500` Range.

I partially succeeded but;

1. It only works for one specific cell.
2. I could not write which tells it is equal or greater than 1. It only works if cell value is equal to 1.

I am truly sorry since I am a beginner at VBA. Helps appreciated.

Please see the whole code below;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("G12")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
With Application
  .EnableEvents = False
  .ScreenUpdating = False
    If UCase(Me.Range("G12").Value) = "1" Then

      Call K999

    End If
  .ScreenUpdating = True
  .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. I just worried if I need to put quotes or not.

Comment: its format is actually percentage. I think I should be using number.

Comment: what does K999 do?

Comment: its my Macro Name :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G1:G500")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo GetOut
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        If Target.Value >= 1 Then
            Call K999
        End If
    End With
End If
GetOut:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Scott; It works just perfect. I am grateful for the support mate.

Comment: I am sorry I just cannot thank you since my reputation is not enough even for it.

Comment: You can click the check mark by the answer, thus selecting this as the correct answer.  The question must be at least 15 minutes old before one is able to select it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '[1]
    If Intersect(Target, Range("G1:G500")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
    '[2]
    If Not IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then Exit Sub
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        '[3]
        If Target.Value >= 1 Then
            Call K999
        End If
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

1. `Intersect(Target, Range("G12"))` checks the target is G12 or not, according to your statement, it should be Range("G1:G500")
2. Since you cannot force the user type a number into the cell, it is safer to check the value is number or not first.
3. "1" is a string, 1 is a number. No need to transtype into string then compare two string.

Comment: thanks for the comments. Quote was definitely unnecessary then. I know about G12 is the single cell. I am still trying to understand range details with the code. Thanks again.